# Can't copy framework to the iPhone filesystem on iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, ssh, filesystem

I am trying to copy RevealServer.framework to /System/Library/Frameworks using Filezilla (because openssh isn't compatible with ios 10).

But I get an error saying that the volume is read only.

I am trying to follow the steps given [here](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/).

Is there an easier way of using reveal on a physical iOS 10 device?

Comment: Dropbear is used for SSH on iOS 10. The reason it doesn't work with Filezilla is likely that FTP isn't set up correctly.